# Metaprogramming, trying to avoid many specializations

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, traits, type-traits

I'm working for adding new content to old program, who uses metaprogramming everywhere. I'm still on c++ 03 and boost.
So here is a problem:
I made template function, that I don't want to specialize because of only differences in four function calls to get specific values:

```
template < typename Message >
void function(const Message & message)
{
    ....
    int value = getHelper...getValue();
    ....
}
```

There are many different Message types :

1. `MessageA: public BaseForA< MessageA >`
2. `MessageB: public BaseForB< MessageB >`
3. `template < typename Appendage >
   MessageAWithAppendage < Appendage >: public BaseForA< MessageA < Appendage > >`
4. `template < typename Appendage >
   MessageB: public BaseForB< MessageB >: public BaseForB< MessageB < Appendage > >`

And two Appendages types:
`SmallAppendage`
`BigAppendage`

There is condition variable in header of each message, depending on it
`getValue()` should get field from message or return zero. This field can be in message itself if type is without appendage,
or in appendage OR at same time at message itself if message is with appendage.

I need something like Base class for messages without appendages and Extended for messages with appendage
something like:

```
template < typename Message >
 class Helper
 {
 public:
    virtual int getValue(const Message & msg)
    {
        if(..)
        {
            return msg.value;
        }
        ...
    }
};

template< template < class > class Message, typename Appendage >
class ExtendedHelper : public Helper < Message < Appendage > >
{
public:
    virtual int getValue(const Message<Appendage> & msg)
    {
        int value = Helper::getValue(msg);
        if(value)
        {
            return value;
        }
        return msg.appendage.getValue();
    }
};
```

After that I thought something like this will work, but it is not:

```
template < class Type >
struct AppendageTraits
{
    enum { appendageIncluded = false };
};

template < class Appendage >
struct AppendageTraits < MessageAWithAppendage < Appendage > >
{
    enum { appendageIncluded = true };
};

template < class Appendage >
struct AppendageTraits < MessageBWithAppendage < Appendage  > >
{
    enum { appendageIncluded = true };
};

template< typename Message , bool >
struct GetHelper
{
    Helper< Message > * operator()( )
    {
       static Helper< Message > helper;
       return &helper;
    }
};
```

EDIT: My traits are now compiles. Is it possible to make this working:

```
template < typename Appendage >
struct GetHelper<MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage>, true>
{
    Helper< MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage> > * operator()( )
    {
        static Helper< MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage>, Appendage > helper;
        return &helper;
    }
};

template < typename Appendage >
struct GetHelper<MessageBWithAppendage <Appendage>, true>
{
    Helper< MessageBWithAppendage <Appendage> > * operator()( )
    {
        static ExtendedHelper< MessageBWithAppendage <Appendage>, Appendage > helper;
        return &helper;
    }
};
```

EDIT: now it have type/value mismatch at parameter 1 for

```
static ExtendedHelper< MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage>, Appendage > helper;
```

expected a class template got.. class template!, but it is not identified somehow.

EDIT:
I resolved this error, it was because of this:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used with or without a template-argument-list. When it is used without a template- argument-list, it is equivalent to the injected-class-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>. When it is used with a template-argument-list, it refers to the specified class template specialization, which could be the current specialization or another specialization.

Correct code:

```
template < typename Appendage >
struct GetHelper<MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage>, true>
{
    Helper< MessageAWithAppendage <Appendage> > * operator()( )
    {
        static Helper< MessageAWithAppendage, Appendage > helper;
        return &helper;
    }
};

template < typename Appendage >
struct GetHelper<MessageBWithAppendage <Appendage>, true>
{
    Helper< MessageBWithAppendage <Appendage> > * operator()( )
    {
        static ExtendedHelper< MessageBWithAppendage, Appendage > helper;
        return &helper;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

My head is hurting after reading all that, but if it's only one operation that you want to specialize, why not make a functor with (possibly templated) overloads (essentially a static visitor):

```
struct ValueGetter
{
  int operator()(const MessageA& ma) const {
    return ma.whatever_we_need_to_do();
  } 
  int operator()(const MessageB& mb) const {
    return mb.whatever_we_need_to_do();
  } 
};

// this is now completely generic
template < typename Message >
void function(const Message & message)
{
    ....
    ValueGetter vg;
    int value = vg(message);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I will need 4 such value geters with 6 specializations each, this is in case i will not find how to make it more compact.

Comment: Keep finding common things to specialise on. Some of the member functions can be templates themselves. They an instantiate further getters.

Comment: That is what i'm trying to achieve. Take a look at updated question, if i will find how to make Helpers working as my traits now, everything will be compact.

Comment: It's difficult to comment without understanding the interfaces better. I would like to help but I am about to board a flight. Hopefully another person can take over. But this structure... Seems complicated. Isn't it easier for all classes to have compatible interfaces?